# How to default to one of many of has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have a User model is it `has_many` things. I want to add a column in my users table for a default thing. How should the migration be?

```
class AddDefaultThingToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :default_thing_id
    end
  end
end
```

Would this be correct?

**Update (perhaps I wasn't clear enough):**

Consider user has_many emails. Email belongs_to user. Now I want to add a default_email column to users table.

Comment: is the default_thing_id same for all Users?

Comment: No. It'll be referencing a unique Thing in the database. Thing also belongs_to User

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
class AddDefaultThingToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :default_thing_id, :integer
    User.reset_column_information
    User.all.each do |p|
     p.update_attribute :default_thing_id, 1
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :default_thing_id
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: default_thing_id is not the same for all users and I don't need the migration to assign for existing records.

Comment: Than you don't have to write that migration part.